# Automating REST API documentation for routes

Tags: scala, spray

Is it possible to automate the documentation of routes in a Spray application?

e.g. Is there perhaps an SBT plugin that generates markdown describing what it knows about the spray routes?

Comment: According https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/0kxLzNRhnU4 there is not much available. All the solutions mentioned in that thread are declarative.

Comment: Have you found a way to document your spray rest api?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon [spray-swagger](https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger) while researching the same thing but I don't know exactly what it does and which stage the project is at.

Comment: It works but imposes annoying requirement to rewrite your routes in such way that they're all methods (where as it's common for Spray apps to define routes as `val`s). It's because Swagger's `ApiOperation` annotation targets only methods.